# How to compute the subject identifier when the redirect URI does not have any host

Tags: openid-connect

In the [OpenID Connect specification section 8.1](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#PairwiseAlg), we can read:

> If the Client has not provided a value for sector_identifier_uri in Dynamic Client Registration [OpenID.Registration], the Sector Identifier used for pairwise identifier calculation is the host component of the registered redirect_uri.

If the redirect URI is `https://foo.bar/my/path`, the host `foo.bar` host will be part of the pairwise ID calculation.

The problem is when a private scheme is used for a native app (see [RFC8252 section 7.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252#section-7.1) e.g. `com.example.app:/oauth2redirect/example-provider`) or when the redirect URI is an URN (e.g. `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob`).

As there is no host with those examples,

- how can I compute the pairwise ID?
- should I reject the client configuration and contraint it to register a sector identifier uri?